# Merging field from one table into another table

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have two tables, one with a field that I need to merge into another table.
The problem that is stumping me is the data from one needs to correspond to the correct existing data on the other.
An example:
Table 1 has the fields Customer, Ticket, and Department. Table 2 has the fields Customer, Ticket, and Price. I need to copy the existing Department field from Table 1 to Table 2, and have it correctly match up to the existing Ticket field, which is identical in both tables.

Comment: You have to be more specific for getting a specific answer. Generally I would answer that you have to use SQL JOINS. Take a look at the following link, where it explains them
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: I don't need to join the entire tables (which in reality have a lot of different fields), I just need to join one field, with respective data, from one table to another. These two tables have different information on the same "tickets", so they are pulling information from one large set of data, and table 2 is just missing a field, but it needs to contain the correct information from that same field in table 1 and correspond to the correct tickets.

Comment: You could create then a view of your join query, selecting the fields you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that you have a phpmyadmin tag, so in mysql you could write the following modified according to your table names and fields.

```
create view finalTable as
select a.customer, a.ticket, b.price, a.department
from table1 as a
join table2 as b on a.ticket=b.ticket and a.customer = b.customer
```